# Triggering of eigenmodes

Tags: dynamics

When conducting an eigenmode analysis, we get a sequence of different modes with their respective eigenfrequencies.

My question is: Are all of those really relevant in every application? Take for a very simple example a spring in zero-gravity that is excited periodically by a longitudinal force. Surely it also has (among others) transversal eigenmodes, but they shouldn't get triggered, right? Since this is a rather abstract example, the same should apply e. g. to the longitudinal modes of a rotating crankshaft. So can we neglect such modes or do we have to assume every system is so imperfect that every mode gets triggered in some way (given its frequency is included in the excitement spectrum)?

Also, e. g. during startup, machines often audibly pass eigenfrequencies. But how can the corresponding mode be triggered if the drive just accelerates rotationally and does not oscillate?

Answer (score 2):

Your first assumption is correct. You can think of the eigenmodes as representing every *possible* mode of vibration of the system. The *actual* motion in a particular situation depends also on the *amplitude* of each eigenmode, and if there is no applied force to excite a particular mode, its amplitude will be zero.

For the rotating crankshaft example, there are two things to consider.

**First,** for a symmetrical system there will be *two* eigenmodes with the same frequency, but displacements in perpendicular directions. A rotational motion of the system can be considered as equal excitation of *both* modes but with phase angles that are 90 degrees different from each other.

As a very simple example, if the axis of rotation (and symmetry) is the $z$ axis, and there are two eigenmodes with frequency $\omega$ and eigenvectors $$U_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad U_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix},$$ the motion $$X = r U_1 \cos \omega t + r U_2 \sin \omega t$$ corresponds to motion around a circle of radius $r$.

**Second,** note that for a general *rotating* system (like a crankshaft) the equation of motion does not reduce to a *linear* eigenvalue equation where all the components of the eigenvectors are real, but to a *quadratic* eigenvalue equation where the different components of the eigenvector at different points are themselves not in phase with each other.

The simplest example of this is the existence of "critical speeds" or "whirling modes" of a rotating component which can be described in terms of gyroscopic (or Coriolis) effects. In the simplest case  (which is a good enough approximation for many practical applications) the quadratic eigenvalue equation can be decomposed into two linear eigenvalue equations which have the same frequencies, but the vectors are 90 degrees out of phase with each other. Look up "shaft whirling" on the web or in a textbook for the details.

Since a real rotating machine can never be perfectly balanced (for example because of geometric imperfections in the components), when it is rotating at speed $\omega$ there will be out-of-balance forces at frequency $\omega$. Those forces can excite some modes when the machine accelerates and its rotational frequency coincides with an eigenfrequency.

Comment: I get that for approximately rotationally symmetric shafts with axis $z$, we can decompose the quadratic eigenvalue problem (whose solutions have different frequencies along the $x$ and $y$ axis) into two orthogonal linear ones with identical frequencies along $x$ and $y$ which give us the basic and higher order modes in $x$ and $y$ direction? And that in every real (i. e. imperfect) system, every eigenmode gets triggered if its frequency is in the excitement spectrum, even if the exciting amplitude is orthogonal to that of the mode (ofc, its resulting amplitude will be small due to damping)?

Comment: +1. It's a nice and detailed answer! By the way, I notice you are the "top user" of the abaqus tag here. There is another abaqus question on a different site: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2055/5 Have you seen it? Is there any way you could help that new user?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the eigenmodes you are referring are attuned to a specific eigenfrequency. The closer you are on that eigenfrequency the more pronounced is similarity to the eigenmode.

So normally, what happens is that when you are doing a eigenfrequency analysis, you are more interested in the first few eigenmodes, which are associated with the lower eigenfrequencies.

One thing you need to consider, is that it is not possible to always decouple a component from the context. For example, the crankshaft. If you look at the crankshaft by itself, then the critical velocity if very high (normally at least 3 or 4 times the maximum operating frequency of the shaft). However, the crankshaft is a part of structure with a larger mass (automobile), which usually has much lower eigenfrequencies.

So in this partiucular example, you are working with a component that operates within a **band** between eigenfrequencies that are below (automobile) and above (crankshaft)the operating frequency.

Now, what happens when you accelerate the crankshaft. Basically, even though the crankshaft passes through the lower eigenfrequencies (and eigenmodes),  it does not stay there for long, in order to resonate and for the eigenmode to become observable.

Comment: Let's assume the shaft is permanently rotated at an eigenfrequency. Then how does the corresponding eigenmode acquire energy if the input is just a constant rotational frequency with no oscillations?

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. The excitation of the particles by rotation is caused by the two orthogonal oscillating translations which make up the rotation (which is what alephzero pointed out I think).